# Para que serve um gists no github?

Tags: github

Qual é a finalidade de um `gists` no `github`?

Em que ele se diferencia para um repositório?

Comment: Não posso perguntar isso aqui?

Comment: Eu acho que votaram por fechar, por um motivo comum nas demais comunidades do SE, falta de pesquisa prévia, eu pessoalmente discordo, pois a pergunta pode ser útil, já que geralmente não temos fontes em portugues sobre o assunto :) +1

Comment: Você também pode usar o Gist para guardar arquivos de configurações importantes. Eu por exemplo utilizo para guardar minhas extensões do Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Com gists você pode compartilhar arquivos únicos ou parte de códigos e até aplicações inteiras, ele é semelhante ao pastebin, todavia cada Gist aceita múltiplos arquivos.

Gists são repositórios GITs, então você pode ver todos `commits` e as modificações completas, pode clonar e fazer forks. Para mais detalhes veja ["Forking and cloning gists"](https://help.github.com/articles/forking-and-cloning-gists/).

### Tipos de Gists

Há dois tipos de gists, *public gists* e *secret gists*. Adicionalmente, se você não estiver logado no github você pode criar um gist, ele será um *gist anonimo*.

- ### Public gists (gist publico)

  Public gists podem ser visualizados e encontrados, elas serão buscáveis, outras pessoas podem usar seus gist tanto quanto você pode usar os deles e se você gostar do trabalho de outra pessoa em cima de um trabalho seu (fork do seu trabalho) você também poderá usa-lo.
- ### Secret gists (gist secreto)

  *Secret gists* não podem ser encontrados por outras pessoas,

  Você pode usar para criar coisas, fazer anotações sem compartilhar, pois não é visível para os demais pessoas nas buscas.

  *Secret gists* não fazem parte da contagem de "repositórios secretos", portanto você pode criar quantos gists quiser.

  > **Atenção:** Secret Gists não são particulares. Se você enviar a URL de gists secreta pra alguém ele poderá visualizar. Se você quer que até mesmo as urls sejam privadas, será necessário criar um repositório no Github ao invés de um gist.
- ### Anonymous gists (gist anônimo)

  Você pode criar um gist sem estar logado no Github, ele será anonimo e pode ser publico ou secreto. No entanto para deletar ele será necessário contatar o suporte do Github ou o administrador do seu site. Neste caso deverá providenciar a url do gist para poder deleta-lo.

### Buscar e encontrar gists de outras pessoas

Você pode encontrar gists de outras pessoas quando você vai até acessar https://gist.github.com/discover, você poderá buscar por idade de criação, última atualização e linguagem. Para isto você pode usar o buscador em https://gist.github.com/search e usar a sintaxe de consulta https://help.github.com/articles/searching-code/

### Embarcando e fazendo download do Gist

Você pode embarcar um gist, em um campo de texto que suporte JavaScript, como uma postagem de blog. Para pegar o código embarcado clique no ícone do clipboard aonde está escrito ***Embed*** Url, como na imagem:

[image: embed gist]

Depois é só colar no campo de texto do seu blog por exemplo. Também é possível copiar a URL do Gist e até fazer Download ou Clonar clicando nos botões *Download Gist* e *Clone Gist* respectivamente, como na imagem.

Fonte: https://help.github.com/articles/about-gists/

Answer (score 11):

Gists são usados pra manter pedaços de código (snippets) que não são especificos de nenhuma aplicação ou não são tão importantes pra terem um repositório só pra eles. Geralmente as pessoas usam os gists para compartilhar (ou manter em um local único) códigos que elas usam com uma certa frequência. Imagine que você tem um pedaco de código que você sabe que irá usar depois (ou quer manter salvo por algum motivo), mas não vale a pena criar um novo repositório pra manter ele salvo e você quer que ele esteja disponível pra você (ou pra outras pessoas) em qualquer lugar que você esteja. É basicamente pastebin, só que com o recurso de controle de versão.

Answer (score 8):

Gists podem ser utilizados para compartilhar trechos de código, um arquivo inteiro ou até mesmo aplicações inteiras.

São muito utilizados para compartilhar trechos de código (conhecidos em ingles por snippets).

Imagine que você tenha algum trecho de código que você queira guardar para acessar em qualquer lugar. Exemplo: Como fazer uma chamada ajax utilizando JQuery.

Para esse caso, você criar um Gist em sua conta do Github e escreve o código que você deseja armazenar. Dessa maneira, em qualquer lugar que você estiver você pode acessar e ver como se faz uma chamada Ajax utilizando JQuery.

Gists podem ser públicos ou privados. Um detalhe importante é que os mesmos são respositórios Git em sua essência.

Answer (score 7):

GitHub é todo o site. Gists são um determinado serviço oferecido no site , ou seja, trechos de código semelhante a pastebin . No entanto, tudo é impulsionado por controle de revisão git , então gists também têm históricos de revisão completa.

para saber mais, consulte = https://gist.github.com/